# Why Nothing >> Just 3 is Nothing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

The signature of the `>>` function in Haskell is this:

```
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
```

And the default implementation is:

```
x >> y = x >>= \_ -> y
```

By that, I understand that the `>>` function always returns its right parameter regardless of the value of the left one. The lambda is not even caring what the value of the left parameter (x) is. Then, why is `Nothing >> Just 3` equal to `Nothing`? Shouldn't it just return `Just 3`, since that is the value of the argument on the right?

I know that any `Just` value, will return `Nothing`, when associated with a `Nothing`, but in this case the `Nothing` is not even being captured by the lambda. What am I missing?

Bonus question, `>>=` is called bind. What is `>>` called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the bind is not even caring what the value of the lambda is!

```
Just x  >>= f = f x
Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
```

Note the `(Nothing >>=)` does not evaluate its second argument.

Comment: Ah, of course... That is what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To really understand what `(>>)` does in this case you have to look at [the definition of `(>>=)` for `Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-Maybe.html#Maybe):

```
(Just x) >>= k      = k x
Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
```

`Nothing >>= k` evaluates to `Nothing` regardless of what the `k` function is. In the specific case of `(>>)`, `k` just happens to be `\_ -> y`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

> > By that, I understand that the >> function always returns its right parameter regardless of the value of the left one

This is the source of your confusion!

`m >>= f` invokes `f` for values it "finds inside" `m`, "combining" the results (where what it means for values to be "found inside" a monadic value and what it means to "combine" are monad-specific).

`m >> n` has to be equivalent to `m >>= \_ -> n`. So for each value it finds inside `m`, it will invoke `\_ -> n` on it. But `Nothing` in the `Maybe` monad doesn't have *any* values "inside" it. So `\_ -> n` can't ever even be invoked on anything in order to ignore it and return `n`! So `Nothing >>= \_ -> n` has to return something that doesn't depend on `n`, since it has no way of calling the function to obtain `n`. There also aren't any values of the wrapped type floating around in this context, so the only option available is simply `Nothing`.

So rather than your intuition for understanding `>>` being that it ignores the left and returns what's on the right, it's better to think that it takes the "monadic structure" of what's on the left and binds that with the monadic value on the right. "Monadic structure" is a hand-wavey term for "everything that defines a monadic value other than the values inside it".

`listA >> listB` does the same thing regardless of the particular values in `listA`, but it matters how many elements are in it. `ioA >> ioB` does the same thing regardless of what value is produced by executing `ioA`, but it matters side effects were done to produce it. `stateA >> stateB` ignores the value produced by `stateA`, but sends the current state to `stateB`. And `maybeA >> maybeB` does the same thing regardless of the particular value inside `maybeA`, but it matters whether there is a value or not. Note that the list case behaves very similarly to `Maybe`; if `listA` is *empty* then `listA >> listB` has to be empty too.

As for your bonus question, when I'm reading code to myself (in my head) I tend to pronounce both `>>=` and `>>` as "bind"; when I'm *looking* at the code as well as pronouncing it there's enough non-verbal awareness of the context that this ambiguity doesn't matter. I actually don't know what I would say to talk aloud with someone about `>>=` and `>>`; maybe "bind" and "forgetful bind"?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It adds a lot of value to the previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to explain the choice.

1. you appeal to the fact that Maybe, unlike IO for instance, has no side effects.   Otherwise not evaluating to the second argument would not make sense.   In this view, it seems like an arbitrary choice from a logical perspective, though it is certainly more efficient, if possibly unexpected.
2. you make Nothing represent an error.  Then an error in the first argument would obviate the need to evaluate the second argument.  It seems like this is the justification chosen by the authors:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-Maybe.html#Maybe

```
-- The 'Maybe' type is also a monad.  It is a simple kind of error
-- monad, where all errors are represented by 'Nothing'.
```

Comment: That makes sense. I don't really argue the logic, I was just not seeing why it returned Nothing, but as @duplode, and leftaroundabout pointed out, it has to do with how the bind function is defined for Maybe. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the question!  I was puzzled by the result as well.

Comment: It makes me feel better to know I'm not the only one who missed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I'd like to add to other good answers.

1. The reason `Nothing >>= f` has to be `Nothing` is because it's impossible to check whether `f` actually uses its argument (without horrible unsafe hacks, at least).
2. `x >> y = x >>= \_ -> y` is not merely the default implementation. The definition of `>>` should always produce the same result as this one. It's only allowed to be overloaded because it can sometimes be implemented more efficiently.